# If I have two local maximums that are same, can I have a global maximum?

Tags: calculus

I have the following function on the interval $[-1,4]$:

$$f(x) = x^3 - 12x$$

When I graph this function, I see on this closed interval, I have two local/relative maximums, which occur at x=-1 and x=4 and both max out at y=16. My question is can I have a global maximum when the only two local maximums I have are the same? Do both count as global maximums?

Comment: Are you sure you have typed your function correctly ? If $f(x) = x^3 + 12x$ then $f(-1) = -13$ and $f(4) = 112$. I don't see where you get 16 from.

Comment: @gandalf61 I meant to write x^3 - 12x. I changed the typo.

Comment: You can only have one global maximum, which here is $16$.  You can attain it at more than one point, as you do here.  A more extreme example is $y=16$, which has the same global maximum but it is achieved everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the given interval, the function $f(x)=x^3-12x$ has a minimum at $x=2$ since $f'(2)=0$ and $f''(2)>0$. This is the only critical point in the interval, hence the maximum must be at the endpoints. In this case we have that $$f(-1)=11$$ and $$f(4)=16,$$ so that the maximum occurs at $x=4$.

**PS.** In the case that a function attains its maximum at more than one point (cf. $\sin x$), then you may pick any one of the points which satisfies other constraints of the problem, or if there are none given, list them all.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a continuous function $f$ on a compact domain $A$ this function is bounded, and the value $\sup_{x\in A}f(x)=:M$ is taken in at least one point of $A$. This value $M$ is then called the *(global) maximum* of $f$ on $A$, an is denoted by $\max_{x\in A} f(x)$.

In the case at hand the maximal value $16$ is taken at only one point of $[{-1},4]$. As a general rule note that the *value* $M$ of the maximum is well defined, and changes little under small perturbations of the problem, but the *place(s)* where this maximum is taken are not a priori uniquely determined and can change abruptly under perturbations.